# How to set the value of a jsonb field with key in dot notation?

Tags: laravel

When I do this:

```
$user = User::find(123);
Illuminate\Support\Arr::set($user, 'foo.bar', 100);
```

I'm getting:

> PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded element of User has no effect in /Users/me/my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php on line 575

```
[
  "bar" => 100,
]
```

And the value is not changed in `$user`.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. But assuming that the json is already an object, have you tried $user->foo->bar = 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```php
$user = User::find(123);
$user->update([
    'foo->bar' => 150
]);
```